# Merge Array Object and Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to merge two array object to become like this example.

```
"feedBackList" : [
        {
            "questionNo" : 1,
            "scoring" : "5"
        },
        {
            "questionNo" : 2,
            "scoring" : "5"
        },
        {
            "questionNo" : 3,
            "scoring" : "5"
        },
        {
            "questionNo" : 4,
            "scoring" : "4"
        },
        {
            "questionNo" : 5,
            "scoring" : "Under 25"
        }
    ]
```

But it not working as expected. It become like this image. what should I do?

[image]

this is my code as your reference

**Component**

```
quesNo = [
    {questionNo: 1},
    {questionNo: 2},
    {questionNo: 3},
    {questionNo: 4},
    {questionNo: 5}
  ];

newFeedback(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      questionNo: this.quesNo,
      scoring: ['']
    })
 }

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.feedbackForm.value);
}
```

> edit demo
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-zb634f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit 1:
What you have tried that is not how you should work with formArray in angular as question can increase. you were adding hardcoded index to each formGroup

Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-wuaa7n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.., but it got this error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.validator is not a function`

Comment: is it possible for you paste html and ts in stackblitz and provide me an link

Comment: I've add stackblitz link in my question

Comment: it is posible to do?

Comment: Yes updating the post please wait